# How to access the directory of the init.el file from elisp?

Tags: init-file

Is there a function/variable to access the directory the init file is in?

This could be: `~/.config/emacs/` or `~/.emacs.d/`, for e.g.

Comment: Your question is not clear: what do you mean by "access"? Are you looking for something like `(find-file (file-name-directory user-init-file))`?

Comment: Any advantage to this over `user-emacs-directory` ?

Comment: No, if `user-emacs-directory` works for you, then it's best to use that. The only difference is that `user-emacs-directory` is a `defconst`, whereas `user-init-file` is a `defvar`, but in most cases this should not matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to access the directory from within the init.el file, this bit of code will give you the name of directory that init.el is in while it is being executed.

`(file-name-directory (or load-file-name (buffer-file-name)))`

If you want to access that directory in another file, then just save that in a variable.