# How to obtain file path from LISP file loaded by command line?

Tags: init-file, directory

Given you started Emacs passing a LISP file through command line:

```
emacs --load .custom.d/init.el
```

how it could be possible to dynamically obtain `custom.el` directory location?

Since the default `init.el` is not used, [`buffer-file-name` is not a possible solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/52434/how-to-access-the-directory-of-the-init-el-file-from-elisp):

```
(file-name-directory (or load-file-name (buffer-file-name)))
```

I have also tried to eval `default-directory` as follows:

```
cd /tmp/username
mkdir custom.d
touch custom.d/init.el
emacs -nw --load custom.d/init.el --eval "(print default-directory)"
```

however the directory from where emacs was invoked (i.e. `/tmp/username` in) is shown, not the `init.el` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs manual node [Action Arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Action-Arguments.html) tells you this about command-line option `--load`:

> Load a Lisp library named `FILE` with the function `load`.  If `FILE`
>   is not an absolute file name, Emacs first *looks for it in the
>   current directory, then in the directories listed in `load-path`*
>   (*note Lisp Libraries::).
>
> *Warning:* If previous command-line arguments have visited files,
>   the current directory is the directory of the last file visited.

This tells you that at the time that command-line switch is interpreted, the value of `default-directory` (the "current directory") is the directory checked first. And that starts out as the directory in which you launched Emacs, which is likely the current working directory in which you issued the command to launch it. See also variable `invocation-directory`.

To get the value dynamically, just evaluate variable `default-directory` at the beginning of your `custom-file`.

Or if you need to get the value outside of Emacs, and if loading your `custom-file` does not change the `default-directory` then you can use switch `-f` just after that `--load custom-file`, to invoke a function that prints the value of `default-directory`.

Comment: I've tried to eval both variables as suggested: `default-directory` correspond to the directory from where emacs was called; `exec-directory` is `void`. What I actually I trying to do is set `spacemacs-start-directory` from inside a custom `init.el` based on its own location.

Comment: I meant `invocation-directory`, not `exec-directory`; corrected now.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "its" in "based on its own location". (Doesn't `spacemacs-start-directory` get set automatically by Spacemacs? I don't use Spacemacs, so I can't help in that regard.)

Comment: @JPVentura `--load` isn't processed until *after* the init file has been processed.  I don't use Spacemacs, but I'm going to guess that this is a problem for your plan, if your goal is to (more or less) use a different init file.

Comment: Although `emacs-startup-hook` runs after all of that, so if Spacemacs waits for that before doing anything with `spacemacs-start-directory` then it's probably ok.